# jquery .height(value) not working in IE

Tags: css, event-handling, jquery

I am using the following code:

```
var winheight = $(window).height();
var headerHt = (0.11 * winheight);
$(".header").height(headerHt)
```

to size `.header` (and other elements) at each window.resize event and upon document.ready. This seems to work fine in Chrome but in IE the new height values are simply not applied to each div. Is there anything obviously wrong I am doing here? What's the best strategy to size for different window sizes dynamically?

Thanks!

Comment: Could depend on the other CSS, or indeed surrounding elements.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem, in the calculation or in setting the height; do you get the correct number if you do an `alert(headerHt);` after the second line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in IE7 & 8..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(){
       var winheight = $(window).height();
       var headerHt = (0.5 * winheight);
       $(".header").height(headerHt);
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. It seems that the height is being set somewhere later in the code as it doesn't work for me...hate IE!

Comment: LOL! have you got any MS filters running on the `.header`, they can interfere with sizing by cropping

Comment: Yep, I have opacity filters! Everything works perfectly on Chrome et al but IE...MAN!

Comment: Ah-ha! (yep it's a tricky monkey is our friend IE!) - so if you remove the filter, does the height work?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 11%;
}
```

By the way, I am assuming that you will have your `.header` always visible and that the scrolling area will be only the content part.

Comment: While its not immediately obvious from this code why I want to resize each div when the window resizes, it is vital for some elements within the page which aren't at 100% height to resize in a fixed ratio with the rest of the elements- that is why. Thanks though!